# Evaluating $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(-4+h)-f(-4)}{h}$, for $f(x)=2x^2+8$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I was completing my limits problem set and stumbled upon this question.

[image: This is a clear image of the problem]

Let $f(x)= 2x^2+8$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(-4+h)-f(-4)}{h}$$

Here was my thought process, solve $f(-4)$ and I got $2(-4)^2+8 = 2\cdot 16+8 = 40$.

Doing this led to my next issue, I don't know what to sub in for $h$. If I subbed $0$ in the limit would not exist as we cannot divide by $0$ but when I enter DNE it's not the correct answer. If someone could help explain what value to input for $h$ and perhaps a better explanation of how to insert $f(x)$ I would greatly appreciate it. I really struggle with substitution problems so please be as simple as possible!

Answer (score 4):

Don't plug anything in for $ h $ right away.  Leave $ h $ in there for now, and treat it as an algebraic expression involving $ h $.  So you got $ f ( - 4 ) = 2 ( - 4 ) ^ 2 + 8 = 40 $, and you can also get $ f ( - 4 + h ) = 2 ( - 4 + h ) ^ 2 + 40 = \cdots $ (this is what Ted Shifrin is asking you to do in the comments).  Now if you subtract these, you should find that some stuff cancels, but there's still some stuff with $ h $ in it.  At this point, if you plugged in $ h : = 0 $, you'd *still* get $ 0 / 0 $.  But if you do one more step of algebra, simplifying the division by $ h $, then you should end up with an expression that does *not* involve division anymore, and *then* you can plug in $ h : = 0 $ to get the answer.

It's worth keeping in mind that there are restrictions for when you can just plug in to evaluate a limit.  This is true *if* your expression is made using several common operations (addition, subtraction, etc), but not every operation whatsoever; and *if* the result is defined (but if the result of plugging in doesn't exist, then that doesn't tell you anything).  Indeed, the real point of limits is when plugging in *doesn't* work, and you need to manipulate the expression some more before you can evaluate it, like here.

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to help, I have a question about how to compute 2(-4+h)^2, is it done as (16+h^2) or (-4+h)(-4+h)?

Comment: Apply your 2nd expression.  $(-4 + h)(-4 + h) $ will generate two middle terms which combine into a single term, effectively doubling the term.

Comment: @nickalh will do, perhaps you know what they mean when they say simplifying the divison of h? Like rearranging or something else?

Comment: What do you get for your numerator?
My purpose and several people here is to help you find the answer which is ultimately far more valuable than simply having an answer.

Comment: I understand that and I get 2(h^2-16h+16)+40 = 2h^2-32h+56

Comment: You know to do $(-4+h)(-4+h)$ because of the order of operations: exponentiation/powers before multiplication.  Then your last comment is basically correct, except that it's $\!{}+8$, not $\!{}+40$, at the end.  (And be sure to multiply the $16$ by $2$; it looks like you got $56$ from $16+40$, when it should have been $2\cdot16+40$, and it's really $2\cdot16+8$.)  Now subtract $f(-4)$ (which you already know is $40$), divide by $h$, and then you'll *finally* be able to plug in $h:=0$ to take the limit.

Comment: And when I speak of dividing by $h$, I mean that if you have something like $(2h^2+3h+4)/h$, then you can write that as $2h+3+\frac4h$.  Except that when you get to this step in your problem, you won't have $2h^2+3h+4$; you'll have something even nicer, and you won't get anything like $\frac4h$ at the end.  Instead, you'll end up with something with no division left in it at all.  But it's easier to see this for yourself than to explain it before it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I posted this answer before seeing that the OP was not well versed in the concept of derivatives.

The limit asked in the question is just the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=-4$. Now we can just differentiate the function to find $$f’(x)=4x$$Putting in the given value $x=-4$, we get the required limit $-4*4=-16$

If you are unfamiliar with the idea of using derivatives, you can instead check out [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), which is suited to your needs here as both the numerator and denominator give $0$ at the limiting location.

You can also try just putting in the supplied function using the given arguments in the limit. What you will get is a polynomial and you can easily derive the limiting value after that. Just don’t try putting in $h=0$, as limits are defined in the surrounding neighborhood of a point, not at the point itself.

Comment: He obviously doesn't know about derivatives, check the comments

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glance Yes saw that right after completing the answer. So added the last part about L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: It also uses the notion of derivative

Comment: @SohamSaha If the OP is not familiar with derivatives, it's improbable he knows L'H rule

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glance please check the edit

Comment: thank you all for helping out, as @julio_es_sui_glace mentioned I do not know derivatives yet and have not heard of the L'H rule, but I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: @jl2005, i apologize for not having seen that you are unfamiliar with this concept.

Comment: @SohamSaha no worries! I appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: This is a great example of why I typically ask a lot of clarifying questions before I spend time on an answer.

Comment: @jl2005 You can check the answer later when you got familiar with derivatives. Furthermore It is suggested to include the important information on the posts instead of comments, so you might want to edit your post and explain what approaches you are looking for. Anyway...I don't understand why someone downvoted this answer.

Comment: @Etemon I don't understand either why it was downvoted, however it is not an adequate answer since it does not really help the OP.